# python raspberry pi digital dashboard for electric car

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

For my master thesis we are building an electric car. For this I need to create a digital dash to show speed, rpm of the electric motor, temperatures,...

I can program in python, but no experience in creating a interface like this. I searched on the internet for examples of digital dashes and found some nice ones. Most of the time they are programmed in qt5.
Now is it possible to program qt5 in python? 
If yes could you help me to get started?

Comment: There is pyQt and pySide if you want Qt but if you are going down that route and wish to use it as a product without releasing the source code after you have finished your Masters, check the Qt Commercial Licence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wxpython for the UI design. Works great.
Recently I've designed a UI for Raspi on wxpython itself.

have a look

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f83dkc9hjhdbbdk/14632693_1206330069428934_64955080_o.png?dl=0

Hope it inspires you. :)